# Sending Broadcast in Service with specified intents

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I am trying to send broadcast but `onReceive()` never gets called.

The service prints the following Toast messages (*`When Bluetooth state is changed`*) -

> "Service created"
>
> "Service Started"
>
> "BT change received !"
>
> "Service Self Stop"
>
> "Background work Stopped"

This is fine for `filter1` but for `filter2`:

The service only prints the following Toast messages (*`When Bluetooth state is not changed`*) -

> "Service created"
>
> "Service Started"

**DataProcessService.java** -

```
public class DataProcessService  extends Service {
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {               
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        IntentFilter filter1, filter2;

        filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);

        if ((intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) 
             && !getSetting("STATUS", "").equals("Connected") && 
             !Common.isAppInForeground(getApplicationContext())) 
        {
            filter2 = new IntentFilter("true");
        }
        else
            filter2 = new IntentFilter("false");

        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);

        sendBroadcast(intent);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    //The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //String action = intent.getAction();
            //BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Toast.makeText(DataProcessService.this, "BT change received !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(intent.getAction().equals("true"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(DataProcessService.this, "Service in Background", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if(intent.getAction().equals("false"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(DataProcessService.this, "Service in foreground", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if ((intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF) || 
                  !getSetting("STATUS", "").equals("Connected") || Common.isAppInForeground(getApplicationContext())) {

                Toast.makeText(DataProcessService.this, "Service Self Stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                stopSelf();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(DataProcessService.this, "Service Continues", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Background work Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public String getSetting(String key, String def) {
        SharedPreferences settings;

        try
        {
            settings = getSharedPreferences("IDDLPref", 0);

            return settings.getString(key, def);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

The purpose of calling `sendBroadcast(intent);` was to call `onReceive()` but it isn't the case.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you

Comment: Sorry, it didn't worked and I m getting the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried sending both broadcasts? with "true" and "false"?

Comment: yes both are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Its because filter2 is registered for the action "true" or "false" depending on its value.
Its working when the Bluetooth state changes because of filter1 and not working at all when its not changed because filter2 is registered to something that doesnt happen. 
If you want it to work without the Bluetooth changed you need to broadcast:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("true"))  // or "false" instead of "true", depending on the IntentFilter's value, or both if you want to make sure it will be called.
```